# Php form filling mySQL table rows with 1's

Tags: php, sql

So I'm making a complaints page for a school project. I started off with a simple PHP form, which worked until I added a

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ PHP code to be executed here }
```

Which didnt work anymore. So I decided to remove that line all together; and whenever I submit any form now, it fills in my MYsql table with 1's even though I am filling the text boxes of the form with text. I don't know if this a problem in mySQL configuration, I have another form that is suffering from the same issue.

I will describe the issue in more details below.

How my "Klacht" Table currently looks like (Excuse my links issue.. I can't post pictures because I dont have more than 10 reps..)

http://i.gyazo.com/6589558c59c4955f5cd48c335d79bdac.png

The structure of it

http://gyazo.com/51ab9d9184a4beb2197ce41f0b98b35b

My form code is a .php file, and I don't get a preview of my PHP code upon pressing the submit button. It just echos the message

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <title>Prototype</title>
    </head>       
    <body>
      <h3>Klacht test</h3>    
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            <br />Test nummer: <input type="text" name="Nr">
            <br />Postcode<input type="text" name="Postcode">
             <br />Datum<input type="Date" name="Datum"> 
             <br />Tijd<input type="text" name="Tijd" >
             <br />Soort klacht
                        <select name="Soort">
                            <option value="    "></option>
                            <option value="Geluid">Geluid</option>
                            <option value="Milieu">Milieu</option>
                            <option value="Veiligheid">Veiligheid</option>
                        </select>
                <!-- Submit button -->
                <br /><input type="submit" value="Versturen">  
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
   </body>
  <?php 

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could not connect to database");
    mysql_select_db("schiphol") or die("could not select database");
    $Nr = isset($_POST["Nr"]);
    $Postcode = isset($_POST["Postcode"]);
    $Datum = isset($_POST["Datum"]);
    $Tijd = isset($_POST["Tijd"]);
    $Soort = isset($_POST["Soort"]);

    $query = ("INSERT INTO klacht (Nr, Postcode, Datum, Tijd, Soort)
    VALUES ('$Nr', '$Postcode', '$Datum', '$Tijd', '$Soort')");
    $resultaat = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error( ));
    if($resultaat) echo "Uw klacht is toegevoegd" ; else echo "ERROR";


    ?>
</html>
```

So.. What am I doing wrong? As I mentioned above, another form is suffering from the same issue. It used to work but doesn't anymore.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First thing, put your php code above the html code. Second thing, you will need `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` to make sure the form was indeed submitted. Third thing. it cannot be `submit`, replace `submit` with the name of the input tag. Fourth thing, it should be `$Nr = if(isset($_POST['Nr']));`

Comment: Can you explain me why I should put my PHP code above the HTML code? Is this self preference or is there are a reason behind it?

Comment: More of self preference. Sorry about "First thing" uh... !

Comment: @bayblade567 No worries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem on isset() it return 0 or 1**

**You use blow code**

```
<input type="submit" value="Versturen">
```

**but you forgot to mention name**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Versturen">
```

**Try this it will work**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <title>Prototype</title>
</head>       
<body>
  <h3>Klacht test</h3>    
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <br />Test nummer: <input type="text" name="Nr">
        <br />Postcode<input type="text" name="Postcode">
         <br />Datum<input type="Date" name="Datum"> 
         <br />Tijd<input type="text" name="Tijd" >
         <br />Soort klacht
                    <select name="Soort">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Geluid">Geluid</option>
                        <option value="Milieu">Milieu</option>
                        <option value="Veiligheid">Veiligheid</option>
                    </select>
            <!-- Submit button -->
            <br /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Versturen">  
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
   </body>
   <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

echo "<pre/>";
print_r($_POST);
//die;


mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db("schiphol") or die("could not select database");
$Nr = $_POST["Nr"];
$Postcode = $_POST["Postcode"];
$Datum = $_POST["Datum"];
$Tijd = $_POST["Tijd"];
$Soort = $_POST["Soort"];

$query = ("INSERT INTO klacht (Nr, Postcode, Datum, Tijd, Soort) VALUES ('$Nr', '$Postcode', '$Datum', '$Tijd', '$Soort')");

echo $query;

$resultaat = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error( ));
if($resultaat) echo "Uw klacht is toegevoegd" ; else echo "ERROR";

}
?>
```

Comment: I already know that in order for the submit PHP code to work, I would need to have a "name" HTML input value; but thanks for pointing that out! I know what I did wrong now; I made use wrong off isset

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think your problem is with isset() funtion. Actually isset() funtion will return a Boolean value based 1 or 0 . so please update your php section without isset() like below and try.

```
<?php 

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db("schiphol") or die("could not select database");
$Nr =$_POST["Nr"];
$Postcode =$_POST["Postcode"];
$Datum = $_POST["Datum"];
$Tijd = $_POST["Tijd"];
$Soort = $_POST["Soort"];

$query = ("INSERT INTO klacht (Nr, Postcode, Datum, Tijd, Soort)
VALUES ('$Nr', '$Postcode', '$Datum', '$Tijd', '$Soort')");
$resultaat = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error( ));
if($resultaat) echo "Uw klacht is toegevoegd" ; else echo "ERROR";


?>
```

Comment: That wouldn't be ideal because; I Would get the undefined index error on each variable

Comment: just assign '' if no value for the field. $Postcode = $_POST["Postcode"] ? $_POST["Postcode"] : '';

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = is set($_POST['some_var']); // this will just return a 1 to $var if the post variable is set
```

Try this instead

```
if(isset($_POST['var'])){ $db_var = $_POST['var'];}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ PHP code to be executed here }` did not work because you did not give a name to your button

```
<input type="submit" value="Versturen">
```

also as `@Azeez Kallayi` pointed out isset() returns boolean value.

Try this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["Nr"],$_POST["Postcode"],$_POST["Datum]",$_POST["Tijd"],$_POST["Soort"])){

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could not connect to database");
    mysql_select_db("schiphol") or die("could not select database");
    $Nr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Nr"]);
    $Postcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Postcode"]);
    $Datum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Datum"]);
    $Tijd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Tijd"]);
    $Soort = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Soort"]);

    $query = ("INSERT INTO klacht (Nr, Postcode, Datum, Tijd, Soort)
               VALUES ('$Nr', '$Postcode', '$Datum', '$Tijd', '$Soort')");
    $resultaat = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error( ));
    if($resultaat) echo "Uw klacht is toegevoegd" ; else echo "ERROR";
}else{?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <title>Prototype</title>
    </head>       
    <body>
      <h3>Klacht test</h3>    
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            <br />Test nummer: <input type="text" name="Nr">
            <br />Postcode<input type="text" name="Postcode">
             <br />Datum<input type="Date" name="Datum"> 
             <br />Tijd<input type="text" name="Tijd" >
             <br />Soort klacht
                        <select name="Soort">
                            <option value="    "></option>
                            <option value="Geluid">Geluid</option>
                            <option value="Milieu">Milieu</option>
                            <option value="Veiligheid">Veiligheid</option>
                        </select>
                <!-- Submit button -->
                <br /><input type="submit" value="Versturen">  
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
   </body>
</html>
<?php}?>
```

```html
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["Nr"],$_POST["Postcode"],$_POST["Datum]",$_POST["Tijd"],$_POST["Soort"])){

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could not connect to database");
    mysql_select_db("schiphol") or die("could not select database");
    $Nr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Nr"]);
    $Postcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Postcode"]);
    $Datum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Datum"]);
    $Tijd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Tijd"]);
    $Soort = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Soort"]);

    $query = ("INSERT INTO klacht (Nr, Postcode, Datum, Tijd, Soort)
               VALUES ('$Nr', '$Postcode', '$Datum', '$Tijd', '$Soort')");
    $resultaat = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error( ));
    if($resultaat) echo "Uw klacht is toegevoegd" ; else echo "ERROR";
}else{?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <title>Prototype</title>
    </head>       
    <body>
      <h3>Klacht test</h3>    
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            <br />Test nummer: <input type="text" name="Nr">
            <br />Postcode<input type="text" name="Postcode">
             <br />Datum<input type="Date" name="Datum"> 
             <br />Tijd<input type="text" name="Tijd" >
             <br />Soort klacht
                        <select name="Soort">
                            <option value="    "></option>
                            <option value="Geluid">Geluid</option>
                            <option value="Milieu">Milieu</option>
                            <option value="Veiligheid">Veiligheid</option>
                        </select>
                <!-- Submit button -->
                <br /><input type="submit" value="Versturen">  
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
   </body>
</html>
<?php}?>
```